# What is the corporate structure of Jurassic World?

Tags: jurassic-park, jurassic-world

What is the corporate structure of Jurassic World? What is the relationship between the Lab and the rest of the park? Why wasn't there more information sharing between the lab and containment when the *Indominus rex* escapes? Was the lab a separate entity from the rest of the park? Also, what is the relationship of InGen to the park?

This question refers to the entire franchise of Jurassic Park.

Answer (score 2):

Dr Wu was working on a secret project with InGen (Hoskins) to create weaponised dinosaurs for use in warfare, the embryos taken by Dr Wu are the outcome of this.

Claire not knowing about this shows that this was hidden from the top most level of the park. The conversation between Dr Wu and Masrani also shows that Dr Wu was pushing the boundaries of the labs intention, and even the CEO of InGen was unaware of the complete goings on in the lab.

As this was outside of the labs remit it made sense that Dr Wu would not share the information of the DNA spliced into Indominus Rex.

Also there appears to be a ban on the Raptors being used in exhibits, this is shown by the fact they are kept in the restricted zone and not used in any exhibitions. Their tendencies to go on rampages probably has something to do with this. As the Indominus has Raptor DNA this would be another reason the lab would hide this fact as she was supposed to be an exhibit creature, the use of Raptor DNA would probably break this rule and Masrani would stop it being exhibited, he has already shown he is not 100% concerned with profits.

InGen (International Genetic Technologies, Inc) is the corporation founded in order to clone extinct life.

It was InGen that opened Jurassic Park and Jurassic World as well as ran the various research facilities such as the one on Isla Sorna.

InGen therefore owns the park, much like Disney owns DisneyWorld et al but the Park will be managed by dedicated staff for that purpose.

John Hammond was CEO (despite an attempted "coup" by his nephew in *The Lost World*) of InGen until his death when Masrani took over.

Comment: How does maserini tie into the ingen structure

Comment: @HSchmale Masrani took over as CEO of InGen following Hammonds death. He mentions this in the film multiple times.

Comment: It is more likely that Marsani was the CEO of the Park Division.  The real CEO of the parent company InGen is not revealed. On Lost World, Hammond was on the board but not in charge.  The guy eaten by the T-rex at the end was the chairman.

Comment: The guy eaten at the end was Peter Ludlow hammonds nephew who was proposing to remove him as CEO this from the script & deleted screen “Whereas the Chief Executive Officer has engaged in wasteful and negligent business practices to further his own personal environmental beliefs Whereas these practices have affected the financial performance of the company by incurring significant losses Whereas the shareholders have been materially harmed by theses losses Thereby, be it resolved that John Parker Hammond should be removed from the office of Chief Executive Officer, effective immediately.”

Comment: He was only proposing and wasn't carried meaning Hammond was still CEO until his death when masrani took over that mantle. This is backed up by Hoskins not making his move until masrani is dead